# Does Using Infura Breaks Decentralization?

Tags: blockchain, infura, decentralization

Decentralized applications have a philosophy: they are immutable,secure and trustless applications. You can connect to Blockchain and be sure about that features.

Infura is a great tool when communicating with Blockchain. However, Infura has its own API which connects you to Blockchain or IPFS. So, as similar to a middle man, doesn't it break the philosophy of decentralization?

Answer (score 1):

Infura could be seen as an application that breaks the overall philosophy of decentralization, but I'd like to think of Infura more like an "ease of use" gateway into the Ethereum structure.

Infura itself is 100% replaceable if people are willing to put in the extra coding time and/or build out their nodes to an individual's specification.

Answer (score 0):

Infura is definitely centralized, but it was a needed short term solution to encourage more development. There are long-term, decentralized solutions being built though! See: mimirblockchain.solutions

(edit: I'm helping build it)

Answer (score 0):

at some extent yes

it breaks decentralization as you are no more directly connected to the network but through a trusted third party!!
it the same as SPV accounts so we relay on a third party to sync data and perform transactions.